# Intel Centrino Centrino Advanced-N 6235 weak wireless reception

Tags: 12.04, wireless, centrino, iwlwifi

I use this card in a computer with Ubuntu 12.04.3 installed. The wi-fi works, but the reception is very weak, compared to a Windows based pc at the exact same place (plus other issues like when external drive plugged, see my other post).

Do I need to install the linux driver for the card (http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi), or is it is already installed automatically by Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Intel wireless devices are troubled by 802.11N implementation in some routers. I suggest you experimentally disable N capability. This is easily reversed if it turns out to be ineffective:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us your result.

Comment: Seems to work, but I don't know why, as my router is an old one and uses only 802.11g. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the driver is already in the kernel, but update your packages using the built-in updater to the most recent ones.

Are You experiencing this same issue with another OS (windows) on the same pc? (a laptop I suppose)

If yes, then I think it's hardware related

1. check if the antenna connectors got loose from the wireless card (you have to take apart the laptop, tell me the model so I can tell you where the wlan card is)
2. try swapping white and black antenna connectors

Comment: It is a Intel NUC, and I did not try Win on it previously. I connected myself the wificard, and firmly connected the antenna wires to the card. The manual clearly indicates which cable connects to which plug, so I think it is ok there. The Intel update tool needs Java installed, what I did, but I could never make the updater work (I just tried Firefox).