# Wireless connection drops on Intel Centrino 6235

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, intel-wireless

I am in a wifi network at school which has secure access and I have been using it for months now, but the problem started a few days ago. Every 3-5 minutes I lose internet access, but retain the network connection. I work in a cubicle block and other people around me have the same computer and do not have the same problem. My hardware is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
```

The dmesg log shows trying to reconnect numerous times:

```
[ 1302.144315] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1302.146992] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:de:84:0e (try 1/3)    
[ 1302.149488] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:de:84:0e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1302.151583] wlan0: associated
[ 1302.151737] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1302.158666] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1302.158675] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1302.158680] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1302.158685] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1302.158688] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1302.158692] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1302.158695] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1302.158699] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1302.158703] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1337.260080] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:de:83:de
[ 1337.264195] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:de:83:de (try 1/3)
[ 1337.267376] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1337.272327] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1337.272331] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1337.272334] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1337.272336] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1337.272338] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1337.272340] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1337.272342] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1337.441577] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1337.441763] wlan0: waiting for beacon from e8:40:40:de:83:de
[ 1338.039990] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:de:83:d1
[ 1338.043779] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:de:83:d1 (try 1/3)
[ 1338.247708] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:de:83:d1 (try 2/3)
[ 1338.451806] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:de:83:d1 (try 3/3)
[ 1338.655819] wlan0: authentication with e8:40:40:de:83:d1 timed out
[ 1338.975657] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:de:84:01
[ 1338.979325] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:de:84:01 (try 1/3)
[ 1339.180150] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:de:84:01 (try 2/3)
[ 1339.384220] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:de:84:01 (try 3/3)
[ 1339.588344] wlan0: authentication with e8:40:40:de:84:01 timed out
[ 1339.916331] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:de:84:0e
[ 1339.920502] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:de:84:0e (try 1/3)
[ 1340.077258] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1340.080528] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:de:84:0e (try 1/3)
[ 1340.084215] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:de:84:0e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=6)
[ 1340.086033] wlan0: associated
[ 1340.086179] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1340.092255] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1340.092260] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1340.092265] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1340.092268] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1340.092271] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1340.092275] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1340.092279] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1340.092282] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1340.092286] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1345.335289] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1345.343514] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1345.343523] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1345.343528] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1345.343532] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1345.343536] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1345.343540] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1345.343543] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1345.600092] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:3c:51
[ 1345.603976] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:3c:51 (try 1/3)
[ 1345.807113] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:3c:51 (try 2/3)
[ 1346.011298] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:3c:51 (try 3/3)
[ 1346.215386] wlan0: authentication with e8:40:40:df:3c:51 timed out
[ 1346.421490] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:3c:5e
[ 1346.426389] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:3c:5e (try 1/3)
[ 1346.627589] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:3c:5e (try 2/3)
[ 1346.831676] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:3c:5e (try 3/3)
[ 1347.035754] wlan0: authentication with e8:40:40:df:3c:5e timed out
[ 1347.188938] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:73:24:61
[ 1347.193573] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:73:24:61 (try 1/3)
[ 1347.220771] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:73:24:61 (try 2/3)
[ 1347.246409] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:73:24:61 (try 3/3)
[ 1347.271798] wlan0: authentication with e8:40:40:73:24:61 timed out
[ 1350.225149] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:66:a1
[ 1350.228523] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:df:66:a1 (try 1/3)
[ 1350.333209] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:df:66:a1 (try 2/3)
[ 1350.334445] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1350.334920] wlan0: waiting for beacon from e8:40:40:df:66:a1
[ 1350.385317] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:df:66:a1 (try 1/3)
[ 1350.389597] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:df:66:a1 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1350.391735] wlan0: associated
[ 1350.391967] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1350.399655] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1350.399664] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1350.399669] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1350.399674] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1350.399677] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1350.399681] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1350.399684] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1350.399688] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1350.399692] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1368.358146] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1368.366211] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1368.366220] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1368.366226] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1368.366230] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1368.366234] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1368.366238] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1368.366241] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1368.655644] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:73:f2:51
[ 1368.660406] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:73:f2:51 (try 1/3)
[ 1368.861864] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:73:f2:51 (try 2/3)
[ 1369.065904] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:73:f2:51 (try 3/3)
[ 1369.068259] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1369.069932] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:73:f2:51 (try 1/3)
[ 1369.074161] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:73:f2:51 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1369.076196] wlan0: associated
[ 1369.076333] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1369.082750] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1369.082759] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1369.082767] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1369.082774] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1369.082780] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1369.082787] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1369.082793] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1369.082799] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1369.082805] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1475.676205] wlan0: deauthenticated from e8:40:40:73:f2:51 (Reason: 252)
[ 1475.691714] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1475.699688] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1475.699697] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1475.699702] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1475.699707] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1475.699710] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1475.699714] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1475.699717] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1478.730685] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:55:21
[ 1478.734432] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:df:55:21 (try 1/3)
[ 1478.735859] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1478.736649] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:df:55:21 (try 1/3)
[ 1478.740235] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:df:55:21 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=14)
[ 1478.742354] wlan0: associated
[ 1478.742418] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1478.746067] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1478.746071] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1478.746073] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1478.746075] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1478.746077] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1478.746079] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1478.746081] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1478.746083] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1478.746084] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1515.056229] wlan0: deauthenticating from e8:40:40:df:55:21 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1515.063691] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1515.072822] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1515.072826] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1515.072829] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1515.072831] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1515.072834] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1515.072836] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1515.072838] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1517.988230] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:55:2e
[ 1517.992297] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:df:55:2e (try 1/3)
[ 1517.997058] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1517.997196] wlan0: waiting for beacon from e8:40:40:df:55:2e
[ 1518.102741] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:df:55:2e (try 1/3)
[ 1518.109021] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:df:55:2e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[ 1518.111267] wlan0: associated
[ 1518.111403] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1518.119766] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1518.119775] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1518.119780] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1518.119784] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1518.119788] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1518.119792] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1518.119795] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1518.119799] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1518.119802] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1664.181679] asus_wmi: Unknown key 7a pressed
[ 1839.423052] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:55:21
[ 1839.427090] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:55:21 (try 1/3)
[ 1839.428306] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1839.433970] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1839.433975] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain,     max_eirp)
[ 1839.433978] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1839.433980] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1839.433982] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1839.433984] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1839.433985] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1839.629396] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:55:21 (try 2/3)
[ 1839.833524] wlan0: direct probe to e8:40:40:df:55:21 (try 3/3)
[ 1840.037560] wlan0: authentication with e8:40:40:df:55:21 timed out
[ 1840.180304] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:df:55:2e
[ 1840.182998] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:df:55:2e (try 1/3)
[ 1840.258938] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1840.261725] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:df:55:2e (try 1/3)
[ 1840.265685] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:df:55:2e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[ 1840.268302] wlan0: associated
[ 1840.268527] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1840.275845] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1840.275855] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1840.275860] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1840.275864] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1840.275868] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1840.275872] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1840.275875] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1840.275879] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1840.275883] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 2083.836601] wlan0: deauthenticated from e8:40:40:df:55:2e (Reason: 252)
[ 2083.839098] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 2083.845959] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 2083.845966] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 2083.845970] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2083.845974] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2083.845977] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2083.845979] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2083.845982] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2083.982047] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:73:f2:5e
[ 2083.986732] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:73:f2:5e (try 1/3)
[ 2084.059524] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2084.062342] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:73:f2:5e (try 1/3)
[ 2084.064863] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:73:f2:5e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=8)
[ 2084.067684] wlan0: associated
[ 2084.067856] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 2084.074586] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 2084.074592] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 2084.074596] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 2084.074599] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 2084.074602] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2084.074604] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2084.074607] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2084.074609] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 2084.074612] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 2110.680427] wlan0: deauthenticating from e8:40:40:73:f2:5e by local choice (reason=3)
[ 2110.705721] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 2110.708682] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 2110.708685] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 2110.708687] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2110.708688] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2110.708690] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2110.708691] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2110.708692] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2113.578170] wlan0: authenticate with e8:40:40:73:f2:5e
[ 2113.581161] wlan0: send auth to e8:40:40:73:f2:5e (try 1/3)
[ 2113.582608] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2113.584011] wlan0: associate with e8:40:40:73:f2:5e (try 1/3)
[ 2113.587971] wlan0: RX AssocResp from e8:40:40:73:f2:5e (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=8)
[ 2113.590012] wlan0: associated
[ 2113.590151] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 2113.593433] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 2113.593437] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 2113.593439] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 2113.593442] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 2113.593444] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2113.593446] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2113.593448] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 2113.593450] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 2113.593452] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
```

I have already tried disabling the 802.11N as mentioned in [Intel Centrino Centrino Advanced-N 6235 weak wireless reception](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398855/intel-centrino-centrino-advanced-n-6235-weak-wireless-reception) or even doing it manually like:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi   
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Both did not work. I even tried the power off feature for it like so:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Also tried disabling IPv6:

```
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a  /etc/sysctl.conf  
echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf  
echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And installing the `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages.

Comment: Installed, rebooted, ran commands and still not working

Comment: Ok lets wait for others to help.

Answer (score 0):

please find my experience below of this problem with an Advanced-N 6235 chip SOLVED:
I had exactly the same issue as described in this bug, with a 6235 wireless chip in my laptop.
After a while, I became increasingly suspicious that it was a hardware issue, not software/kernel/driver.
I bought a newer replacement 6235 chip, popped in my laptop, and the problem is now solved.
This was on U 13.04, and I'm now on 14.04, and it has been running perfectly ever since.
So there is definitely no problems with the kernel or driver in Ubuntu for this chip. I can't comment for other chips, but if you have a 6235 chip, I would strongly suggest purchasing a new replacement, fitting it, and you will find your issues resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get-upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-jaunty
```

Then reboot