# Is this a bad wireless card?

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, centrino

I have been having a weird wifi card issue.

First, the hardware details from `lshw`:

- product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
- wifi card: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150
- computer maker: Asus

I have a Wireless router which other computers can easily connect to. The router has WPA personal security on it. When I was bringing up the computer on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, [here's what I have observed in `/var/log/syslog`](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/85b8ffe1bb26e227ce32).

Can I do something without the card replacement? Or am I out of luck?

**Update**: I tried the suggesting given by @karel. Some more info on the wireless card now being identified properly
$> lshw -c network

*-network

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 67
   serial: 40:25:c2:c2:4b:c0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-24-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 ip=192.168.0.111 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
   resources: irq:51 memory:de800000-de801fff
```

---

**Update 1**: $> iwconfig

---

```
wmx0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

---

**Update 2**: I did:

- modprobe -r iwlwifi
- modprobe iwlwifi

and then observed [this log](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/4833662a973b7a7d6b2f) in /var/log/syslog.

---

**Update 3**:

[modinfo iwlwifi is here](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/6d75d4aa0e22315ebb43). I did an rmmod on iwldvm and then modprobe iwldvm.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/398855/intel-centrino-centrino-advanced-n-6235-weak-wireless-reception/398959#398959) about the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 wireless card. The  Intel Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 is an `iwlwifi` card, so please edit your question and  add the `iwlwifi` tag below your question to help bring your question to the attention of networking and wireless experts.

Comment: @karel, Thanks, I tried the suggestion in that thread to no avail. :-(

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet clear what fixed my problem but it seems to work. There are a bunch of things that appear to have to come together for it to work well. I am somewhat puzzled why this has to be this hard.

- It seems that having **options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1** in /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi helps.
- Suggestions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454427/network-issues-since-trusty) seem to help, given that we started having these issues since Trusty.
- Experimenting with country regulatory domain (as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465848/frequent-deauthentication-from-wifi-reason-6-in-ubuntu-14-04)) seems to have helped.
- I also tried with a few kernels, not sure if that helped. Right now, I am using the kernel that Trusty comes with (3.14.1-031401-generic)

All of this is empirical, as you can see. But it seems to help. I am updating this answer using the same wireless card that was not working at all.

Comment: It's still flaky. And when it goes 'bad' again, I get a stack trace with:
-----
Sep 16 16:57:02 mypc kernel: [   13.883303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: bad EEPROM/OTP signature, type=OTP, EEPROM_GP=0x00000007
Sep 16 16:57:02 mypc kernel: [   13.883305] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: EEPROM not found, EEPROM_GP=0xffffffff
Sep 16 16:57:02 mypc kernel: [   13.883307] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unable to init EEPROM
----

Comment: The onset of the error seems to be [this](https://gist.github.com/kedarmhaswade/3cd13cc9b5f11aaf47ec)